# How to put top (middle?) drawer crisper hanger back in refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator

We have a GE GSE23GSKKCSS refrigerator.  We were taking all the internal pieces out to do a deep cleaning and now we can't get the "hanger" or whatever you call the piece that the top crisper drawer hangs from back in.

Here is what the interior looks like where the piece is supposed to go.  I have circled the four "pegs" that it I think it's supposed to somehow fit over.  The arrows are pointed at the "hanger".  The glass piece has been removed while I try to put it in.

[image: pegs and hanger]

Here is what the back of this piece looks like, with the red line and arrow showing how I'm trying to fit it over the peg.  There is another corresponding thing on the opposite side so both sides are trying to slide over the two back pegs at the same time:
[image]

I can fit them over the pegs in the back.  But there are two indentions that it appears are supposed to fall down over the two front pegs.  But I cannot push the piece back far enough for them to reach.  The arrows show the way I think the pegs are supposed to go and the two "X"es are the approximate location of the back pegs.
[image]

I can get one side or the other to fit, but whenever I try push both sides back at once, only one side slides all the way back.  If I try to jiggle it to get the other side back, then the side that is already back pops back out, leaving a gap at the side:
[image]

The arrow below shows where the piece has failed to drop down on the peg because the back won't slide onto the back peg, while the "X" shows the right side where the peg is hidden because it was able to drop down properly:

[image]
I found the [owner's manual](https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/assembly/GSE23GSKKCSS) online, but it doesn't even mention this piece, much less tell how to put it back in.

Update: It has been brought to my attention that this is not actually the *top* drawer.  There is another drawer above this one; in the third picture you can see it above the vent on the left and it's also visible in the fifth picture.  Thus, there is a large gap and as it doesn't have the crisper slider on the front I wasn't counting it as one of the crisper drawers.

Update 2: Well I figured it out somehow, but it was kind of by accident and I'm not exactly sure what I did so I'm not sure I can answer my own question. However, if anybody else has this question it *is* possible to get it back in, it just has to be pushed and pulled just so.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the shelves reversed.  You say this is the "upper" one, but in the parts diagram (your link) the lower on (410) has a rounded front like the one in your doesn't-fit photo.  OTOH the upper one (531) has a round indentation in the back, unlike either of the shelves in your photos, so I'm not certain of this answer but see where this takes you.

[image]

Comment: I must be blind, what page did you find that diagram on?

Comment: After studying this a bit further I think I may have just described the position wrong.  In the diagram the 410 is above the second drawer from the bottom and has glass (409) that comes out of it, which mine does.  There is another drawer above this that is already in (472) but it doesn't have the "crisper" slider in the front and there is a big gap between the bottom shelf and it, so I wasn't counting it as a crisper drawer.  Perhaps I should reword to say the "middle" drawer.

Comment: Oh well, so much for that theory.  The parts diagrams are further down the page that you linked, this one is "Fresh Food Shelves".

Comment: Well here is nothing but a big tease https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWkzZm9Aio8

Comment: lol yeah it's like they never thought somebody would remove this part to clean it.

Comment: well i figured it out... but I'm not exactly sure what I did.  I had left it in the position of the last picture and just pulled and pushed somehow and it snapped into place!

Comment: I suspect you didn't push the back far enough onto the pegs to allow the front pegs to slide into the slots.